# Select multiple columns with single case statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, case

I have requirement where in value of three columns depend on the value of single column . Say I have a table as

```
A | B | C | D | E
```

A,B,C,D and E are the columns and requirement is to get values of A,B and C as such if the value of column D is '1' else the values for A,B and C will be NULL.

I tried using CASE statement but it seems like we have to use CASE multiple times

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN D = '1' 
            THEN A 
            ELSE NULL, 
    CASE 
        WHEN D = '1' 
            THEN B 
            ELSE NULL;
```

I was looking for something like just one CASE and select the appropriate values. Is there some way we can achieve that or this is the recommended way.

Comment: `CASE` **expression**; SQL Server doesn't support `Switch` (`Case` Statements)

Comment: Nothing wrong with multiple case expressions.

Comment: You can drop `ELSE NULL` as that is the default

Comment: Thank you @Larnu for the response . I will take this into consideration

Answer (score 2):

Three `case` expressions is the most natural method.  However, you could also use `outer apply`:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM t OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT t.a, t.b, t.c
      WHERE d = '1'
     ) x;
```

Comment: Thank you @GordonLinoff , I will surely try this .

Answer (score -1):

If your table has a unique identifier, for example `ID`, you can also join the table to itself. Assuming your table name is `test`:

```
SELECT      test2.A, test2.B, test2.C, test.D, test.E
FROM        test
LEFT JOIN   test test2 ON
                test.ID = test2.ID AND
                test.D = '1';
```

If you set a UNIQUE composite index on columns `ID` plus `D` it can be an efficient query.
In the above query you need `test.D` and `test.E` to retain original values from these columns, regardless of `D`'s value.